# Assign text from file to variable in Ruby without returning text

Tags: ruby, io, interpreter, irb, logparser

I am trying to parse some access logs with Ruby, the file itself is 363MB. I'm working in IRB and when I try to assign the text from the document to a variable `data = logs.read` it begins returning all the text into the interpreter, which at 363MB is an issue.

How do I assign the contents of a file to a variable *without* returning the value back in the interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your irb as below :

`irb --simple-prompt --noecho`

- `--simple-prompt` is to get the IRB prompt as `>>`
- `--noecho` is to off the echo on IRB

Here is an example:

```
C:\>irb --simple-prompt
>> x = 2
=> 2
>> exit

C:\>irb --simple-prompt --noecho
>> x = 2
>>
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks, will mark correct in a few minutes when SO will let me.

Comment: @Priti What is the use of the `--simple-prompt` option in this case?

Comment: @toro2k I use this to get the prompt as `>>`. I like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `;` and then enter any operator, for example:

```
data = logs.read; nil
```

It will output just `nil`.